# Java: Weird String/Integer error on single PC

Tags: java, date

This code:

```
private boolean yearIsValid(String v) {
   if (Utilities.noString(v) || v.length() < 4)
     return false;
   v = v.substring(0, 4);
   if (!Utilities.IsInteger(v))
     return false;
   int i = Integer.parseInt(v);
   return i >= 1800 && i <= 2100;
 }
```

on one single computer, it returns false for the input value 2015-05-28T06:26:27-05:00. On every other computer it runs on (100s all across the world) it succeeds. The computer on which it fails is localised to USA.

I have no idea what to look for (except I'm pretty sure it's not a secret BOM, the value comes from an XML attribute in a DOM)

For reference

```
public static boolean noString(String v) { 
  return v == null || v.equals(""); 
}

public static boolean IsInteger(String string) {
    try {
        int i = Integer.parseInt(string);
        return i != i+1;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: What does `Utilities.noString` do?

Comment: which `return false` is actually being executed?

Comment: Is this the noString function? http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/me.fhir/fhir/0.12.0-RELEASE/org/hl7/fhir/utilities/Utilities.java#Utilities.noString%28java.lang.String%29

Comment: *"I have no idea what to look for"* Have you tried to add some debugging messages? Do you know if the argument is correct or not? Do you know which `return` statement was used to return the "wrong"/unexpected result?

Comment: @samgak It seems so, this class also has the misspelled `IsInteger` method: [source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/me.fhir/fhir/0.12.0-RELEASE/org/hl7/fhir/utilities/Utilities.java#Utilities.IsInteger%28java.lang.String%29)

Comment: yes that's the source. Don't know why IsInteger has the wrong case. In this context it's not the simplest to add debug messages, so I wanted some idea of what to look for before I started that cycle

Comment: Well, your code is pretty straight forward without any "error-prone" statement. So I would suggest to check 2 things: Is the argument really the one you expect (is the format the same?) and has each client the same Version of the used library, which contains the `Utilities` class?

Comment: @GrahameGrieve Please edit your Question with updates and additional details, rather than scattered across comments. Notice the `edit` link found just below your Question and its tags (if using a web browser rather than app).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why so complicated? Why not just:

```
private boolean yearIsValid(String v) {
   if (v == null) {
       return false;
   }
   try{
      int i = Integer.parseInt(v.substring(0, Math.min(4, v.length)));
      return i >= 1800 && i <= 2100;
   catch(NumberFormatException e){
      return false;
   }
 }
```

Comment: because you make some assumptions about both the input and the result, Who told you that the year will be in the format you expect and will not need some cleanup or formatting? Why 1799 or 2101 is not a valid year?

Comment: @aviad: did you see the condition `i >= 1800 && i <= 2100` in the question?

Comment: @aviad *Why 1799 or 2101 is not a valid year?* - from the original post above.

Comment: true. my bad. however, the assumptions part still stands.

Comment: @aviad They are the same as in the question - original string is not changed, just checked.

Comment: if (Utilities.noString(v) || v.length() < 4) this is what is missing in your answer IMO

Comment: @aviad No, this is checked in *if (v == null) {
       return false;
   }* and *Integer.parseInt(v.substring(0, **Math.min(4, v.length)**))*

Comment: So you are guessing what Utilities.noString(v) does?

Comment: anyway, i believe the point here is why in a single computer, for the same input a different output is provided. Writing the method simpler is not an answer for me but an improvement

Comment: @aviad It certainly does not any cleaning, because the original value is used for parsing. It can check for null, empty or blank value - and all those checks are included in my code.

Comment: @FranMontero I believe, that the *false* value does not return the code in question, but the code in *Utilities* class, which we can't see.

Comment: guess stays guess until we know what Utilities.noString does.

Comment: @aviad Utilities.noString(v) and Utilities.IsInteger(v)

Comment: it's not rocket science, this one: public static boolean noString(String v) {
     return v == null || v.equals("");
   }

Comment: Well, I changed to this code above, though as far as I could figure the outcome would be the same. And the error went away. So who knows...

Answer (score 0):

If all your input values (the mentioned XML attribute) are in the same format as the example, then I would suggest another route altogether.

## Date-Time Libraries

An alternate route would be using a date-time library. Specifically, either the new [java.time package](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) built into Java 8 and later, or the [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) library (which inspired java.time). Both use the standard ISO 8601 formats for parsing/generating string representations of date-time values. This includes the format used by your input string.

### Benefits

- One important benefit would be attention to time zone. A time zone is crucial in determining a date (and therefore a year).
- Another side-benefit is that in parsing your strings, the date-time library will throw a specific Exception when attempting to parse improper input text. I suspect/guess that may have been the problem with your apparent glitch. You should specifically trap for that parsing exception to track such bad inputs.

### java.time Example

The [`ZonedDateTime`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html) class can parse strings in ISO 8601 format. Just call the static [`parse`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html#parse-java.lang.CharSequence-) method.

```
ZoneId zone = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" );

String input = "2015-05-28T06:26:27-05:00";
ZonedDateTime zonedDateTime = null;
try {
    zonedDateTime = ZonedDateTime.parse( input ).withZoneSameInstant( zone );
} catch ( DateTimeParseException e ) {
    // … Handle this case of bad input string data. Log it, and so on.
}
int year = zonedDateTime.getYear( );
Boolean valid = ( ( year >= 1800 ) && ( year < 2100 ) );

System.out.println( "Input: " + input + " adjusted to zone: " + zone + " = " + zonedDateTime + " and gives year: " + year + ". Valid: " + valid );
```

When run.

```
Input: 2015-05-28T06:26:27-05:00 adjusted to zone: America/Montreal = 2015-05-28T07:26:27-04:00[America/Montreal] and gives year: 2015. Valid: true
```

#### Half-Open

Even better, use date-time objects entirely without the focus on year as integer. Define the date range you have in mind, with the time zone you have in mind. Then test if that range contains your input value. For the "contains" test, use the often-used Half-Open approach. In Half-Open, the beginning time is *inclusive* while the ending is *exclusive*.

If you went this route, there is no need to assign the time zone on the input date-time object, no need to call [`withZoneSameInstant`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html#withZoneSameInstant-java.time.ZoneId-). The time zones need not match when comparing with [`isBefore`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/chrono/ChronoZonedDateTime.html#isBefore-java.time.chrono.ChronoZonedDateTime-).

```
ZonedDateTime start = ZonedDateTime.of( 1800, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, zone );  // Could mark both 'start' and 'stop' as "static" if they do not vary at runtime.
ZonedDateTime stop = ZonedDateTime.of( 2200, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, zone );  // Use 2200 rather than 2100, for Half-Open approach to comparison.
Boolean valid2 = ( ( zonedDateTime.isBefore( stop ) ) && ( ! zonedDateTime.isBefore( start ) ) );

System.out.println( "Does the interval from " + start + " to " + stop + " contain " + zonedDateTime + " : " + valid2 );
```

When run.

```
Does the interval from 1800-01-01T00:00-04:54:16[America/Montreal] to 2200-01-01T00:00-05:00[America/Montreal] contain 2015-05-28T07:26:27-04:00[America/Montreal] : true
```

Comment: These are overkill for this particular use, but I had not run into ZonedDateTime before - I will use it elsewhere. thanks